# swift 3 convert string to objectID

Tags: macos, swift3, xcode8

i work with swift 3 and nsoutlineview.
i would like to save the objectID of a core data record into a textfield.
so i have to convert it into a string:

```
txtFied.stringValue = "\(CoreData[outlineView.selectedRow].objectID)"
```

how can i convert it back to an NSManagedObjectID?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've done this via the persistent store coordinator's `managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation:)` method, as outlined below:

```
    // Convert NSManagedObjectID to a string, via the uriRepresentation method.
    let objectIDString = <your managed object ID>.uriRepresentation().absoluteString
    ...
    // Use the persistent store coordinator to transform the string back to an NSManagedObjectID.
    if let objectIDURL = URL(string: objectIDString) {
        let coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = <reference to your persistent store coordinator>
        let managedObjectID = coordinator.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: objectIDURL)
    }
```

Comment: thank you for the answer. bu what is my "persistent store coordinator" ??

Comment: Happy to help! :)